# Fastest way to set a column value based on a condition and looping through a different data set

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes. I want to create a new column in frame1 based on data from frame2.
df1:

```
Name      State
person1   CA   
person2   TX   
person3   FL   
person4   CA
```

df2:

```
State   Rent
CA      2000
TX      1000
FL      500
```

I want to update the df1 to look like this:

```
Name      State   Rent
person1   CA      2000
person2   TX      1000
person3   FL      500
person4   CA      2000
```

Currently I am doing this:

```
for x in df2['State']:
    df1.loc[data.State.str.match(x), 'Rent'] = df2[df2.State.str.match(x)].Rent
```

It works fine for small dataset. I have about 5 Million entries in df1 and about 2000 entries in df2. How do I optimize this code for runtime in pandas? I suspect the str.match is the root cause of this runtime. Any insight into reducing runtime?

Would converting the second dataframe into a hash improve runtime?

Comment: a merge should do the trick : ```df1.merge(df2,on='State',how='left')```

Comment: Thanks @sammywemmy. Works like a charm